# Orient DB - Export database with Specified datatables

Tags: java, export, orientdb

Im working with orient db where i have to export specified data tables using java. Here is the code im working with:

```
ODatabaseDocumentTx db = new ODatabaseDocumentTx("remote:localhost/sampleDB").open("admin", "admin");

        try {
            OCommandOutputListener listener = new OCommandOutputListener() {
                @Override
                public void onMessage(String iText) {
                    // System.out.print(iText);
                }
            };

            Set<String> abcd = new HashSet<String>();
            abcd.add("sample_demo1_OnlineShopping");

            System.out.println(abcd);

            ODatabaseExport export = new ODatabaseExport(db, "DataCont/Data.gz", listener);

            export.setIncludeInfo(false);
            export.setIncludeClusterDefinitions(false);
            export.setIncludeSchema(false);
            export.setIncludeIndexDefinitions(false);
            export.setIncludeManualIndexes(false);

            export.setIncludeClasses(abcd);

//          export.exportRecords();
            export.exportDatabase();
            export.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            db.close();
        }
```

The problem is, its not including any classes. Output file was like this:

```
{"records":[]}
```

But when i tries without the "setIncludeClasses" it prints all the classes available in the database. What would the issue for this problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line to:

```
abcd.add("sample_demo1_OnlineShopping".toUpperCase());
```

I haven't found it in the documentation, but **includeClasses** is expecting classes in UpperCase (same for **excludeClasses**).

See [the source code](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/blob/master/core/src/main/java/com/orientechnologies/orient/core/db/tool/ODatabaseExport.java#L190).

Comment: It works. Thanks man. But there is an issue. It retrieves only the specified class. It doesnt retrieve the child classes of it. Is this supposed to be or is there any issue in my code.

Comment: The source code I linked in my answer doesn't seem to care about subclasses.